# Show/Hide button's on other button's click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 3 buttons on my aspx page and when I click button 1, I'm looking to show button2 and button3 along with "div and gridview" on client side.

Here is the code snippet:

```
$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
    if ($("#divshow").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#<%=gvdetails.ClientID%>").show();
        $("#<%= Button2.ClientID %>").show();
        $("#<%= Button3.ClientID %>").show();

        $("#divshow").show();
        $("#divshow").addClass("scrollDiv");
        $("<%=gvdetails.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
        SetDefaultSortOrder();
        return false;
    } else {

        $("#<%=gvdetails.ClientID%>").hide();
        $("#<%= Button2.ClientID %>").hide();
        $("#<%= Button3.ClientID %>").hide();

        $("#divshow").removeClass("scrollDiv");
        $("#divshow").hide();
        return false;
    }
});
```

But my button2 and 3 are not visible on button1. Someone please suggest me how to solve this one.

Comment: Can you post your CSS? My guess is that #divshow isn't hidden how jQuery specifies the ":hidden" selector: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the scriptlet use a binding expression:

```
$('#<%# Button1.ClientID %>')
```

And you can use chaining. So try this:

```
$("#<%# Button1.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
    var $divShow = $('#divShow');
    if ($divShow.is(":hidden")) {
        $("#<%# gvdetails.ClientID%>, #<%# Button2.ClientID %>,#<%# Button3.ClientID %> ").show();

        $divShow
            .show();
            .addClass("scrollDiv");
        $("<%# gvdetails.ClientID%>").tablesorter();
        SetDefaultSortOrder();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#<%# gvdetails.ClientID%>,#<%# Button2.ClientID %>,#<%# Button3.ClientID %>").hide();

        $divShow
            .removeClass("scrollDiv");
            .hide();
        return false;
    }
});
```